# Deshabilitar click en un link con javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, html

he estado leyendo y he encontrado harto sobre esto pero.. ninguno me sirve o lo estoy aplicando mal.

Encontré tres formas de hacerlo y son las siguientes.

La única finalidad de esto es mostrar la hora y lo hace, pero si una persona da click te dirige a la página.

```js
$("#time_is_link").on('click', function (event) {
    // filter out clicks on any other elements
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'A' && event.target.getAttribute('aria-disabled') == 'true') {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#time_is_link").on("click", function(event){
    if ($(this).is("[disabled]")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
$("#time_is_link").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<a href="https://time.is/Argentina" id="time_is_link" rel="nofollow" class="isDisabled" style="font-size:36px; font-weight: bold"></a>
                    <span id="Argentina_z107" font-family: 'Agency FB' style="font-size:34px"></span>
                    <script src="//widget.time.is/t.js"></script>
                    <script>
                                time_is_widget.init({ Argentina_z107: {} });
                    </script>
```

Lo estoy aplicando mal?
Gracias

Comment: No puedes eliminar el atributo `href`?

Comment: El problema no está en el etiqueta `<a>` ni en el atributo `href`, el problema es que esa librería agrega en el `<span id="Argentina_z107">` un span más, con un evento `onclick="location='http://time.is/'"`. Y por más que lo intente deshabilitar, como se genera dinámicamente no pude lograr hacer que no se ejecute.

Comment: o sea, no se puede hacer nada??

Comment: hay alguna otra alternativa para mostrar la hora?

Comment: Si, hay varias, la podés hacer vos usando otra librería, si es que querés utilizar zona horarias diferentes. Por ejemplo [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Entonces voy a probar con eso, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) con [`moment-timezone.js`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) podés obtener el [formato](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) y hora de cada región de la siguiente manera y luego lo mostrás en el span.

```js
// evento que se dispara cuando el DOM cargó
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arg = $('#Argentina_z107');
  
  // ejecuto cada 1000 milisegundos
  setInterval(function() {
    var hora = moment().tz('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires').format('H:mm:ss');
    // muetro la hora
    arg.text(hora);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment.js timezone with data -->
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>


<span id="Argentina_z107"></span>
```

A tener en cuenta: el archivo que tenés que usar es el de `moment-timezone-with-data.js`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

No hay atributo deshabilitado para hipervínculos. Si no desea vincular algo, deberias eliminar la etiqueta `<a>` por completo o eliminar su atributo `href`, en cuyo caso no funcionaria.

Comment: No es una solución, si bien está correcto lo que decís, lo que le pasa es otra cosa.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con lo siguiente

```
<a href="https://time.is/Argentina" onclick="nada()">Enlace No Funcional</a>
<script>
    function nada(){}
</script>
```

al llamar ser un enlace que al tener por prioridad el OnClick, llamara a la función "nada()" que, no hace nada, haciendo que al clickear tu enlace, no ocurra nada

Comment: Como añadido se puede poner `onclick="return false;"` y no necesitas el script, o simplemente quitar el enlace y dejarlo en un div por ejemplo

Comment: El código no funciona.